# Rethinkdb slowed down drastically after adding a shard

Tags: rethinkdb, sharding, slowdown

For a year we were working on single rethinkdb instance but couple days ago we were able to spin up a second machine and create a shard of the existing database on it.

After tables (~60M of fairly simple records) finished balancing between shards we experienced extreme slowdowns in reads (reads are now, on average 10 times slower) and because of this - connection timeouts.

The slowdown is visible in queries that use `between` on datetime fields. We tried both connections trough rethinkdb proxy and straight to one of the shards. There seem to be no speedup when connecting using proxy.

Is this expected behavior? Can this kind of slowdown be avoided?